# Pandas merge 2 csv with a similar column but different header name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to merge 2 csv file with a similar column but different header name.

a.csv:

```
id name country
1 Cyrus MY
2 May US
```

b.csv:

```
user_id  gender 
1 female
2 male
```

What I need is, c.csv:

```
id name country gender
1 Cyrus MY female
2 May US male
```

But the result I get when I use the below code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on=['id'],right_on=['user_id'], how='outer')
df3.to_csv('c.csv',index=False)
```

The result I get:

```
id name country user_id gender
1 Cyrus MY 1 female
2 May US 2 male
```

Comment: I guess df3.drop('user_id ', inplace=True, axis=1) would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rename the `user_id` column in `df2` to `id`. Since the name is the same, it won't be duplicated.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('b.csv').rename(columns={'user_id': 'id'})
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='outer')
```

Otherwise you can drop the `user_id` column adter the merge.

```
df3 = df3.drop('user_id', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on='id',right_on='user_id')
Out[35]: 
   id   name country  user_id  gender
0   1  Cyrus      MY        1  female
1   2    May      US        2    male
```

Or `concat`

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'),df2.set_index('user_id')],1).reset_index()
Out[38]: 
   index   name country  gender
0      1  Cyrus      MY  female
1      2    May      US    male
```